# Using Functions in the LC3 Assembly Language

Tags: function, lc3

I need to know how to write a simple function in LC3 and using it in the main program.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of creating a label and then jumping to it. Once you're done with that subroutine then return back to the main code.

```
.orig x3000

    AND R0, R0, #0      ; clear R0

    JSR FUNCTION
    PUTc
    HALT                ; TRAP x25

FUNCTION
    ADD R0, R0, #10     ; Store the value of 10 into R0
    RET                 ; return back to the main code

.end
```